# How to retreive one single value in comma separated columns form, from a table in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have a column with values like the one below. I need to separate value number 10 from each row in SQL sever (being value 1 the first one in the string, second after the first comma and so on).

Here is my column:

```
Row 1    N,l,S,T,A,,<all>,,N,A,N,N,N,Y,Y,,Y,Y,Y,,AA,SA
Row 2    M,,A,S,AS,SS,AS,N,N,N,N,Y,Y,Y,ENTERPRISE,S,,A
Row 3    L,,A,D,S,A,A,AA,Y,Y,Y,YNN,N,N,N,N,A,AA,AD,D,D
```

I need the values in place 10 to use in a table (I can discard the rest of the values in the string). How do I get only that one value in a column? The table I have has more than 1,000 rows so this is just an example, I need a code that can take the value of each position in the row as the source of the string.

Here is the result:

```
Row 1    A
Row 2    N
Row 3    Y
```

Comment: Take a look at `CHARINDEX()`. You can us it to find the 9th occurrence of `,` in `C3: `CHARINDEX(',',C3,9)`. Then get the substring from there until the next occurrence of `,`.

Comment: Yes, I have used this code:  declare @s nvarchar (200) = N,l,S,T,A,,<all>,,N,A,N,N,N,Y,Y,,Y,Y,Y,,AA,SA,AS,SA'
;with cte as 
(
    select 1 as Item, 1 as Start, CHARINDEX(',',@s, 1) as Split
    union all
    select cte.Item+1, cte.Split+1, nullif(CHARINDEX(',',@s, cte.Split+1),0) as Split
    from cte
    where cte.Split<>0  
)   
select SUBSTRING(@s, start,isnull(split,len(@s)+1)-start) as Div1
from cte 
where Item = 10

Comment: And I have the value retrieved. But how can I bring each result in a new column?

Comment: Well you will need to modify your table first to add the column, then you can populate it. `ALTER TABLE cte ADD Div1 nvarchar(100)` for example. Then `UPDATE cte SET Div1 = (SELECT...)`

Comment: This question does not read well, and is somewhat misleading for prospective answers. Please add more detail as to what exactly you need, in terms of output

Comment: There are numerous "Split String" functions that will split a string based on a delimiter, and number the results so you can use WHERE Element = 10 in your SELECT to pull only the 10th element out of each. A simple search for "string split" or "split string" will find you dozens of options (the built in SQL2016 function won't work because it doesn't number the results).

Comment: @jimmy8ball, Thanks, you are right. I have updated the question, I hope it is now more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clean your string first for any special chars, such as the occurrence of your all value contained in

< >.

After cleaning the string you should have each value consistenly delimeted that can then be presented to an XML function, this function will isolate values from a delimeted string based on its numeric position from left to right.

```
DECLARE @TEST TABLE (STRING NVARCHAR(150));
INSERT INTO @TEST
VALUES 
('N,l,S,T,A,,<all>,,N,A,N,N,N,Y,Y,,Y,Y,Y,,AA,SA'),
('M,,A,S,AS,SS,AS,N,N,N,N,Y,Y,Y,ENTERPRISE,S,,A'),
('L,,A,D,S,A,A,AA,Y,Y,Y,YNN,N,N,N,N,A,AA,AD,D,D')

SELECT 
CONVERT(XML,'<x>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(STRING,'>',''),'<',''),',','</x><x>')+'</x>').value('/x[10]','NVARCHAR(150)') [VALUE 10],
STRING
FROM @TEST
```

This does rely on a clean string being passed to the function, if the string is not clean of special chars or consistently delimeted then the function will fail.

```
VALUE 10    STRING
A           N,l,S,T,A,,<all>,,N,A,N,N,N,Y,Y,,Y,Y,Y,,AA,SA
N           M,,A,S,AS,SS,AS,N,N,N,N,Y,Y,Y,ENTERPRISE,S,,A
Y           L,,A,D,S,A,A,AA,Y,Y,Y,YNN,N,N,N,N,A,AA,AD,D,D
```

For Clarity, you would use this function like so:

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(XML,'<x>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(STRING,'>',''),'<',''),',','</x><x>')+'</x>').value('/x[10]','NVARCHAR(150)') [VALUE 10]
FROM YOURTABLE
```

Simply replace STRING in the function with your column name, and that should do it.

Comment: @SQL_NewUser upvoted as question now provides more clarity.

Comment: Thanks. That works for the 3 rows in this table, but how can I make that each string value of my column with more than 1000 strings go through that code?

Comment: you just simply use it like SELECT CONVERT(XML,'<x>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(STRING,'>',''),'<',''),',','</x><x>')+'</x>').value('/x[10]','NVARCHAR(150)') [VALUE 10] FROM YOURTABLE, where the STRING represents your current string column.

Comment: The 3 records are for test purposes only